# LINQ2SQL: how to delete entity by retrieving it from datagridview?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datagridview, itemdatabound

I have a datagridview and attached list of Employees to it, somthing like this:

```
IQueryable<Employee> data = (from em in db.Employees
                             where em.StationID == stationID
                             select em);
dgvView.DataSource = data;
```

Now I want to delete specific Employee by selected row in datagridview:

```
using (PetrolNetwork db = new PetrolNetwork())
                {
                    Employee empl = (Employee)dgvView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
                    db.Employees.DeleteOnSubmit(empl);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
```

Not surprise, that I've got exception "*Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached.*"
When I replace this code by:

```
Employee employee = (from em in db.Employees
                                         where em.ID == empl.ID
                                         select em).Single();
                    db.Employees.DeleteOnSubmit(employee);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
```

all work correctly, **but** in sqlprofiler we can see one extra select to database to retrieve our specific employee, and then delete from statement.
 How I can delete my employee, when I got it from DataBoundItem from datagridview without any extra select statements? One approach that I can see is custom sproc to delete by ID. May be there is any other best approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately with LinqToSql, you need to select the item to delete before deleting it.

Using stored procedures as you mentioned is one option.

Another is using L2S to execute [custom SQL statements](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx).

```
result = db.ExecuteCommand("Delete from Employees WHERE id = '2'")
```